# Button Focus effect with inkscape

Tags: inkscape, button, focus

[image: Pause Button]

[image: Pause Button Focused]

These two images are pause-buttons for a program. The first one shows the button in its default state and the second one when it is being focused on.

I am wondering how the person, who made these buttons, did the focus effect? I looked all over the Internet but couldn't find a tutorial or a hint on how to do something like that.

I recreated the first button with Inkscape. It has a background layer (the gray background as seen in the first picture ) and a button layer which contains the pause symbol (just two rectangles). But now I am clueless on how to proceed.

I hope I am in the right place with my question. Also if this is somehow not possible with Inkscape, I can only use Gimp. I have no photoshop :(

Comment: http://ionflux.org/en/inkscape_glow_tutorial_01.html

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, looks like it will help. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

For the round glow effect, use a radial gradient. You can do that in the fill and stroke area by clicking the circle.
The glow of the actual pause sign can be achieved using a blue box below the pause shaped the same. You assign a light blue to it and blurring int a bit. If you want the glow not to start directly at the border of the pause sign but with a small gap, you can add a border to the pause sign in the same color as the background.